# Need help accepting 7 double values representing tips earned by a waiter each day during the week

Tags: c#

Here's the problem:

> Write a program named TipsList that accepts seven double values
>   representing tips earned by a waiter each day during the week. Display
>   each of the values along with a message that indicates how far it is
>   from the average.

This is what I have figured out so far.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] tips;
        tips = new double[7];

        double one = tips[0];
        double two = tips[1];
        double three = tips[2];
        double four = tips[3];
        double five = tips[4];
        double six = tips[5];
        double seven = tips[6];

        double average = (one + two + three + four + five + six + seven) / 7;

        //Now I am trying to take the tip 1,2,3,4,5,6, and 7 that the user has entered
        //And display the diffrence of tip 1,2,3,4,5,6, and 7 from the average
        //So one-average = tip 1 console.Write tip1 ??????

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {

            Console.Write("Please enter the amount of tips earned by waiter #" + i + ".");

            tips[i] = Console.Read();

            Console.Write("tips 1????????????HELP");

        }

    }
}
```

I have an understanding of how I would try and do it and think I should do

`one-average = tip 1 console.Write tip1` ?????

but C# doesn't like it. I just don't get it still does C# only let me do it in 1 determined way.

Comment: First of all, breathe. And then edit your question so that you can focus specifically on your _programming_ problem.

Comment: Where's the homework tag when you need it?

Comment: "the programming language is stupid"..dont use such words..

Comment: Should I edit that out?

Comment: I didn't read past your code so first of all `tips.Average()` second, for a list of differences do `tips.Select(x => AverageVariable - x);` (I've purposely left out the bit to make it in- **toList**

Comment: First of all how can I just do tips.Average do I have to declare tips and average and second of all do I have to convert them or anything?

Comment: you want to print the tip amount along with text or difference between the tips..

Comment: Average is an existing method in the linq namespace (`using System.Linq`)

Comment: Yes I that is correct I want to print the tip amount along with a message that indicates how far it is from the average.

Comment: You can't calculate the average before you have read the data...

Comment: "how far it is from the average" ...can u give an example..

Comment: This is based upon the 7 numbers the user enters.

Comment: The average is a average of the 7 numbers

Comment: I need to prompt the user 7 times for 7 tips then display the 7 tips back to the user with the difference between each tip from the tips average.

Comment: first calculate the average of seven tips.then for every tip make a deduction from average..

Answer (score 2):

I just realised this is for a class so I'd stay away from Linq, it would be too obvious for any teacher.

Simply just write out the value of each taken away from the average

```
foreach(double tip in tips)
{
Console.WriteLine(Average - tip);
}
```

**Edit** Just realised the problem is getting the input.

Your better off to use `TryParse` as this will handle invalid input

```
while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tips[i]))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thats not a valid number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use somthing like this:

```
double[] tips = new double[7];

for (int i = 0; i < tips.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter the amount of tips earned by waiter #" + i + ": ");
    tips[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

double average = tips.Average();

//without linq
/*
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tips.Length; i++)
{
    sum = sum + tips[i];
}
double average = sum / tips.Length;
*/

for (int i = 0; i < tips.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tip #" + i + " is: " + tips[i] + " - The difference between the average is: " + Math.Abs(tips[i] - average));
}

Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: I am confused if I had to even promt the user for 7 numbers

Comment: The question is Write a program named TipsList that accepts seven double values representing tips earned by a waiter each day during the week. Display each of the values along with a message that indicates how far it is from the average. Maybe I just put 7 values in my code do I have to be promoting the user for 7 values?

Comment: No, Hard Coding is evil!

Comment: How are we supposed to know? Ask your instructor.

Comment: @user2676862 - Your actual code is not actually that far away from completion according to your requirement.

Comment: Because that's that exact question from a C# book not from an instructor. And its a programming exercise.

Comment: "accepts seven double values" means it does not spontaneously start with 7 double values...

Comment: See the books pretty clear what it want and anyone who know C# can  complete this just fine. I don't know enough syntax to.

Comment: This is pissing me of I have other homework and I could of had a English paper done by know yet it takes 10 times longer to get 8 lines of C# done. Programming is a bitch.

Comment: try to read the book over from start. maybe you missed some things. P.S. programming is not a bitch, you just need to learn it. its easy for some and impossible for others.

Comment: This book sucks its the Microsoft® Visual C# 2012, 5th Edition

Comment: In my exp, online tutorials are easier. but the book explains things you would not normally find in a tutorial

Comment: @user2676862 If you know how to solve the problem, you can Google for the individual required syntax. You don't need to know anything about C# to do this.

Comment: Like something that walks you through step by step

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks Dukeling this does work sometimes if I somewhat know what could work to do this and am to find and piece together the syntax found on the internet.

Comment: This is turning into a conversation, but all you have to do is think about it logically, what must be done and the order it needs to be done, code what you can and if you stuck on a step google how to do the specific step. for example, `how do i get the average of a double array in C#` https://www.google.co.za/search?q=how+do+i+get+the+average+of+a+double+array+in+C%23

Comment: that is something you should google: https://www.google.co.za/search?q=where+is+linq+used+in+C%23

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this program myself, and i realized that it is actually asking for a 2D array hence the 7 inputs for the 7 days of the week. you can accomplish that by using`double[,] tips = new double[7, 7];`Then you would use 2 loops to access each index element

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
     {
       for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
              tips[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
      }`
```

Then you would first get an average(i.e add the sum of all indexes per day(7) or for the week(49) depending on how accurate you would want your data to be, then divide)